# Python flask to display remote user name in the web page

Tags: python, flask

I am using below Python Flask code for reading remote user name in the web page.
and name = Request.remote_user.name is printing me REMOTE_USER as output can some one really tell me which particular configuration in web server i need to look at ? or how to get the real remote_user name into the web page.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, Request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
import flask
import os
import getpass

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html',name=name)

name =flask.Request.remote_user.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run('localhost',8000)
```

and hello.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
   <h1>Hello- {{ name }} </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation, so this becomes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Beware that `flask.Request` ist the request class, whereas `flask.request` is the actual current request. `flask.Request.remote_user.name` is simply `REMOTE_USER`, since that is the properties name. `flask.request.remote_user` is what you want.

Comment: @YSel flask.request.remote_user is printing output as Hello- <environ_property REMOTE_USER>

Answer (score -1):

You can use

`print(request.headers)`

this will give you list of all session variables.

for getting a remote user

`print(request.headers[X-Remote-User])`

Answer (score -1):

I guess we can use below code snippet initially to identify all headers and then the required one i.e. `remote user`

## Identify all the Headers & values passed in the request

```
print("Headers: ", vars(request.headers))
for header in request.headers.items():
    print(header)
```

#### then `remote_user` is available via key name `X-Remote-User` in the `header`.

```
remote_user = request.headers.get("X-Remote-User")
print("Remote User: ", remote_user)
```